# How do I count unique values that need to meet multiple criteria in Excel?

Tags: excel, unique, criteria, countif

I would like to count the number of ''mail opens'' by unique people per day.
I have included a small example below.
So in this case, because Harry opened the mail twice on day one, I only want to count him once.
I do want his ''mail open'' on day 2 to count towards the total numbers of mails opened on day two, though.

The result I should be getting from this is:
Day 1: 2
Day 2: 2

I have tried Countifs, unique combined with filter, etc. but have not yet been succesfull. I feel like they should be combined somehow, but keep struggelnig to get to the correct answer. Any help would be highly appreciated.

| person | action | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Harry | mail open | 1 |
| Harry | mail open | 1 |
| Harry | click | 1 |
| Joseph | mail open | 1 |
| Harry | mail open | 2 |
| Maria | mail open | 2 |
| Maria | click | 2 |

Comment: how tdoes your filed Countifs() look like?

Answer (score 0):

Per your request:

> I would like to count the number of ''mail opens'' by unique people
> per day.

If the input data is in the following range `C2:E8` you can use the following formula:

```
=LET(days, E2:E8,
  BYROW(UNIQUE(days), 
  LAMBDA(day, COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C8, 
  (D2:D8="mail open") * (days=day))))))
)
```

Here is the corresponding screenshot:

[image: sample excel file]

If you want the result including the day number, you can concatenate the result via `HSTACK` function as follow in `I2` cell:

```
=LET(days, E2:E8, HSTACK(UNIQUE(days), 
  BYROW(UNIQUE(days), LAMBDA(day, 
  COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C8, (D2:D8="mail open") * (days=day))))))))
```

If you prefer expanding down the formula instead, just populate separately the unique days in `I2-I3` cells and on cell `J2` put the following formula and expand it:

```
=IF(I2="","", COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$8, 
  ($D$2:$D$8="mail open") * ($E$2:$E$8=I2)))))
```

### Explanation

We use `LET` function to shorten the formula avoiding repetition the same range. In our case `E2:E8` named as `days`.

Now for each unique `days` (`UNIQUE(days)` by row) via `BYROW` function we count the number of unique **person**, based on filter conditions `mail open` and for a given `day`. The *and* condition is stablished in the `FILTER` function by multiplying each condition:

```
FILTER(C2:C8, (D2:D8="mail open") * (days=day))
```

Now we just need to count the unique elements (via `COUNTA` and `UNIQUE`) of the `FILTER` result (the elements of `C2:C8` that matches the conditions).